# How to limit VSTS Extension access to specific users or groups?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We are working on a VSTS Extension and want to only allow select users/groups to access and utilize the features of the extension. This extension essentially adds a dashboard that's linked from the gear menu.

If a user doesn't have access to the various data that the extension pulls from VSTS, they will have parts of this extension not work - but we do want to hide the extension and its link entirely if we don't explicitly authorize a group to view it.

I've checked various pages within the [Develop Extensions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/) as well as the [Security documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/index) but haven't found anything relevant to a topic like this.

I'm wondering if perhaps I could check for the user's identity details and deny access based on that, but the [Identities API isn't yet functional](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/issues/131), so I think that option isn't available to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no way to specify the users or groups to access the installed extension.

I posted an user voice [VSTS extension restrict for specified users or groups](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32926549-vsts-extension-restrict-for-specified-users-or-gro) to suggest this feature. You can vote and follow up.